# Avoid phtread_create error 11

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, overflow

I am trying to write a C program using POSIX threads to divde a square into 4 and then divide some of those 8 again and again until some conditions are met.. so in general the program goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define checkResults(string, val) {             \
 if (val) {                                     \
   printf("Failed with %d at %s\n", val, string); \
   exit(1);                                     \
 }                                              \
}

void *editSquare(void *arg);

void divide(void *arg){
    int i,rc;
    Square *s = (Square *) arg;
    pthread_t thr[4];

    Square divs[4];
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        rc=pthread_create(&thr[i],NULL, editSquare,(void *) &divs[i]);
        checkResults("pthread create",rc);
    }
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        rc=pthread_join(thr[i],NULL);
        checkResults(" pthread join ",rc);
    }

}

void *editSquare(void *arg){
    int i,rc;
    Square *s = (Square *) arg;
    if ( !some conditions ){
        // do stuff
        // ...
        divide(s);
    }
    else{
        //do stuff
    }
}

int main(){
    Square sq;
    //initialize sq
    divide(&sq);
    return 0;
}
```

this can go pretty deep and at some point i'm getting error code 11 at pthread_create.. I understand it creates too many threads for my cpu leading to error.. 
Is there a way/technique I can control/manage the number of active threads and stall some threads, until some others end, and create them afterwards??
and in general is there a way to virtually create N threads which don't actually run parallel after a number of max_threads, but enter some sort of FIFO queue where they wait to be created?

(i can get more specific with the program or the struct if you think it is needed...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm getting error code 11

That's `EAGAIN` on Linux.

> Is there a way/technique I can control/manage the number of active threads and stall some threads, until some others end,

Sure: create a global thread counter and a condition variable. Any new thread increments the counter (under a mutex). When the counter is about to exceed some limit, don't create any new threads, but wait on condition instead. Exiting threads should decrement the counter and signal condition.

This will likely not solve your problem though due to the recursive nature of your problem (you'll get into a deadlock when all threads must create additional threads before they can exit, but you are out of available threads).

The better solution is to create a work-queue, and a thread pool. Any thread from the pool picks up next work item from the queue when it's available, and appends new work items to the end of the queue.

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually I kinda thought to create some like that work queue you 're saying but I have trouble using the wait/signal cond.. when do i send the signal? and under what condition the "work queue" wait ?
if it's not too much for you I would appreciate showing me where to put those signal and wait commands.. thanks in advance! :D